# Could somebody help me design a venn diagram for this problem?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Local NY residents were asked which area teams they support.  122 support at least one team.  16 support only the Yankees, 16 support the Yankees and Giantss, and 35 support the Yankees and Mets.  Of those who support another team in addition to the Yankees, 2 support both.  1 support only the Giants, and 45 support the Giants and the Mets.  2 residents do not support any of the teams. Calculate the probability for each given event.

Comment: so we need to know a few things how many total people A, how many support yankees B, how many support giants C and how many support Mets C, we also need to know How many support Yankees and giants BC, How many giants and mets CB and how many yankees and mets CD and those who support all three BCD,.and how many don't support any E. in the end we should have A=B+C+D - CB - BD -CD +BCD+ E

Comment: A is the big square B,C,D are the big circles CB,BD,CD,BCD are the respective overlap, and E is the remaining space

Answer (score 1):

In summary, we are given:

$\mu(Y^\complement,G^\complement,M^\complement)=2
\\ \mu(Y\cup G\cup M) = 122
\\ \mu(Y,G^\complement,M^\complement)=16 
\\ \mu(Y^\complement,G,M^\complement)=1\\ \mu(Y,G)=16
\\\mu(Y,M)=35
\\\mu(M,G)=45
\\\mu(Y,G,M)=2$

Then: $\mu(Y^\complement,G,M) = 43, \mu(Y,G^\complement,M)=33, \mu(Y,G,M^\complement)=14$.  Can you see why?

Can *you* find: $\mu(Y^\complement, G^\complement, M)$?

Comment: So would M just be 13?